# Local base for indiscrete topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

a local base of the point is a collection of sets such that in every open neighbourhood of there exists a base element contained in this open neighbourhood. ...
This is the definition of local base but what is the local base for indiscreet topology?

Comment: If you care enough to change it: the spelling here should be "indiscrete", rather than "indiscreet"... People will understand what you intend, in any case.

Comment: Local base for the indiscrete topology is the indiscrete topology itself.

Comment: @freakish: Not quite; the local base should not contain $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every point of $X$ in the indiscrete topology has but one neighbourhood: $X$ itself. So a local base at any $x$ is just the set $\{X\}$.